# Is it better to perform direct pointer operations or []

Tags: c++, c, arrays

I have a 2d array. I need to perform a few operations on it as fast as possible (function will be called a dozen of times per second, so It would be nice to make it efficient).

Now, let's say I want to get element `A[i][j]`, is there any difference in speed between simply using `A[i][j]` and `*(A+(i*width+j))` (ignoring the fact that I need to calculate i*width+j, let's say I already have this value)?

Comment: Why don't you test and find out?

Comment: @chris because last two times I tested I was still proven wrong by people with better knowledge in setting proper compiler flags

Comment: The answer is "yes". Use whichever makes the intent of your program clearer.

Comment: There are two errors in `A+(i*width+j)`. First, it is performing arithmetic with a pointer of the type of `A[0]` (one row of the two-dimensional array, which is an array of the ultimate elements), but you want arithmetic with a pointer of the type of `A[0][0]` (one of the ultimate elements). Second, the result is a pointer, but you want an element. A correct expression would be `*(&A[0][0] + i*width + j)` or `*(A[0] + i*width + j)`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With all the optimizations turned on, there should be no difference - not only in the timing, but also in the code the compiler generates for these two constructs.

The biggest difference from a programmer's point of view is readability. The first construct immediately tells the reader that he's dealing with a 2D array, while the second one requires some thinking (is it a row-major order, or a column-major order? Where is the `width` calculated? What was the reason to choose this way over a more obvious 2D array syntax?). That is why the first construct is preferable in real-life scenarios.

Comment: Do I as a programmer actually have any controll over how program accesses the memory? Or is my code merely a suggestion?

Comment: @Xyzk Your code has (nearly) full control over accessing your data in memory, apart from situations when you cannot tell the difference - i.e. when the logic of the program does not change one way or the other.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the quality of compiler, I think the `[]` notation can result in faster code. The reason is that when you use pointers, the compiler can't be sure that pointer aliasing is not occurring and this can preclude certain optimizations.

On the other hand, if the `[]` notation is used, those concerns do not apply and the compiler can get more aggressive with applying optimizations.